# TypeError: setOpenModal is not a function (ReactJs)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am getting an error when trying to display a dialog modal in ReactJS. First, I pass the state of the dialog into a page, which is Work.jsx, which renders a component named ProjectCard. Inside the component ProjectCard, I pass in the states of the opening and closing of it. Now, inside the ProjectCard component, I have an event listener onclick. When somebody clicks on that component, the dialog will show. As soon as it shows, I change its state to true and pass in the data it's supposed to render, which is the ProjectDetails component given below. I get an error in the ProjectCard component when I click it, saying that setopenmodal is not a function. Can someone please explain what it means? Here is the code... The error is inside the ProjectCard component on the card click event listener.

The App.js Code

```
function App(){
  const [openModal, setOpenModal] = useState({ state: false, work: null });
  return (
    <Router >
    <div className="app">
      <Navbar />
      <Header />
      <About />
      <Work openModal={openModal} setOpenModal={setOpenModal} />
      {openModal.state && (
        <ProjectDetails openModal={openModal} setOpenModal={setOpenModal} />
      )}
</div>
</Router>
)}
```

The Work Page Code

```
const Work = ({ openModal, setOpenModal }) => {
return(
<motion.div
        animate={animateCard}
        transition={{ duration: 0.5, delayChildren: 0.5 }}
        className="app__work-portfolio"
      >
        {filterWork.map((work, index) => (
          <CardContainer>
            <ProjectCard
              key={index}
              work={work}
              openModal={openModal}
              setOpenModal={setOpenModal}
            />
          </CardContainer>
        ))}
      </motion.div>
)
}
```

The Project Card Component

```
const ProjectCard = ({ work,setOpenModal }) => {
  const handleClick = () => {
    setOpenModal({ state: true, work: work });
  };
  return (
    <Card onClick={handleClick}>
      <Image src={urlFor(work.imgUrl).url()} alt={work.name} />
      <Technologies>
        {work?.technology.map((technology) => (
          <Technology>{technology}</Technology>
        ))}
      </Technologies>
      <Details>
        <Title>{work.title}</Title>
        <Date>{work.date}</Date>
        <Description>{work.description}</Description>
      </Details>
      <Members>
        <Title2>Members :</Title2>
        {work.members?.map((members) => (
          <Avatar src={urlFor(members.imgUrl).url()} alt={members.name} />
        ))}
      </Members>
      <Tags>
        <Title3>Tag(s) :</Title3>
        {work?.tags.map((tags) => (
          <Tag>{tags}</Tag>
        ))}
      </Tags>
    </Card>
  );
};
```

The ProjectDetails Component

```
const ProjectDetails = ({ openModal, setOpenModal }) => {
  const work = openModal?.work;
  return (
    <Modal
      open={true}
      onClose={() => setOpenModal({ state: false, work: null })}
    >
      <Container>
        <Wrapper>
          <CloseRounded
            style={{
              position: 'absolute',
              top: '10px',
              right: '20px',
              cursor: 'pointer',
            }}
            onClick={() => setOpenModal({ state: false, work: null })}
          />
          <Image src={urlFor(work.imgUrl).url()} alt={work.name} />
          <Title>{work?.title}</Title>
          <Date>{work.date}</Date>
          <Technologies>
            {work?.technology.map((technology) => (
              <Technology>{technology}</Technology>
            ))}
          </Technologies>
          <Desc>{work?.description}</Desc>
          {work.members && (
            <>
              <Label>Members</Label>
              <Members>
                {work?.members.map((members) => (
                  <Member>
                    <MemberImage src={urlFor(members.imgUrl).url()} alt={members.name}/>
                    <MemberName>{members.name}</MemberName>
                    <a
                      href={members.githubLink}
                      target="new"
                      style={{ textDecoration: 'none', color: 'inherit' }}
                    >
                      <GitHub />
                    </a>
                    <a
                      href={members.linkdinLink}
                      target="new"
                      style={{ textDecoration: 'none', color: 'inherit' }}
                    >
                      <LinkedIn />
                    </a>
                  </Member>
                ))}
              </Members>
            </>
          )}
          <ButtonGroup>
            <Button dull href={work?.codeLink} target="new">
              View Code
            </Button>
            <Button href={work?.projectLink} target="new">
              View Live App
            </Button>
          </ButtonGroup>
        </Wrapper>
      </Container>
    </Modal>
  );
};
```

The Problem is inside the ProjectCard Component on the card on click
i was expecting For The Modal To Display as i don't understand whats the issue with the code

Comment: I wonder if the `Router` component overrides props for its direct children and thus `setOpenModal` wouldn't make it to `ProjectCard`? Can you try using wrapping a `Context` around your app and managing your state that way instead of passing props directly?